# Circular disk in a convex domain

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

Let $\partial \mathcal D$ be the smooth boundary of a convex domain $\mathcal D$ in the plane and let $\kappa (P)$ denote the curvature of the osculating circle at point $P \in \partial \mathcal D$. Denote the point of maximum curvature by $P^*$ so that $\underset{P}{\text{max}} \{\kappa (P)\} = \kappa (P^*)$ and consider a circular disk $\mathcal C$ whose radius is $r^*=\frac{1}{\kappa (P^*)}$.

Is it true that if this circular disk $\mathcal C(r^*)$ is placed (from inside) tangential to $any$ boundary point then it is completely inside the convex domain $\mathcal D$ and for a similar question with dimension higher than $2$?

Comment: I'll bet "yes," but I'm having difficulty proving it...  (For *non*-convex, the answer is "no" and I have a simple example.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I feel your pain...